# How do I make zsh compsys fallback to local files for commands?

Tags: zsh, completion

I think the simplest example is that if a command does not exist, then `invalid-command <TAB>` will present a list of files that you can tab complete on.

If the command (and completion) does exist, then on exhausting the completions, hitting `<TAB>` will either produce the bell sound e.g:

```
prompt > yarn test <TAB>
```

Or it will result in `- no more arguments -` e.g:

```
prompt > yarn run test <TAB>
- no more arguments -
```

To produce the above behaviours I currently have the following:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _correct _approximate _files
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format "- %d -"
zstyle ':completion:*:corrections' format "- %d - (errors %e})"
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-prompt '%S%M matches%s'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*:manuals' separate-sections true
zstyle ':completion:*:manuals.(^1*)' insert-sections true
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose yes
zstyle ':completion:*' rehash yes
zstyle -e ':completion:*:approximate:*' max-errors \
          'reply=( $(( ($#PREFIX + $#SUFFIX) / 3 )) )'
```

I had hoped that adding _files to the end of `:completion:*` it would fallback to the current files if no other completion was available, but it appears I was naive in this assumption? :)

I think I'd be able to go into the _command completion definitions and add this to each one individually, but as a general fallback this seems quite appropriate (and matches prior experiences).